# Start Rails server with a require statement by passing an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

Sometimes I use pry and pry-debug to debug my Rails application. This is only a problem if I use additional Ruby processes, like in my case I use Sidekiq.

In order to make the Sidekiq  code debugable as well I have to add the following statement

```
require sidekiq/testing/inline
```

This is fine, but it's very cumbersome to comment it every time in and out. Is there a way to automate this? I thought maybe it's a good idea to create a sub-class environment for this. Take all the parameters like the `:development` environment, but add this requirement and then I could start it like so

```
$ rails server -e debug
```

Does that make sense? I just don't know how to clone or subclass an environment, create a `debug.rb` in `config/environments`, and then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution that comes to my mind is little bit hackish, but at least it should work for you ;).

```
require sidekiq/testing/inline if ENV['DEBUG_ENV']
```

Then just:

```
$ DEBUG_ENV=1 rails server
```

I would go for debug environmenr only if you have more things to change.